# Delete operation by Confirm Modal using Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, confirm, knockout-mvc

I have this following code for making a confirm dialog using Bootstrap modal. I have two modal forms. First form - editable, for add, edit and delete records. When I am trying to delete a record, I'm using second confirm modal with "Ok" and "Cancel". I need to check if not selected items before deleting and blocked first form.

I am trying to implement delete row confirmation modal. I dont know how to do it.

My modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade hide" id="modalConfirm">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-bind="click: function () { closeFrmModel($('#modalConfirm')) }" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3>@Resources.Warning</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center">
            <span>@Resources.DelQuestion</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="modalOk" aria-hidden="true">@Resources.ButtonOK</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-bind="click: function () { closeFrmModel($('#modalConfirm')) }">@Resources.ButtonCancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Dropdown code:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="pane-triggers">    
                    <div class="navbar-text">
                        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Activity&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: function () { showTrigger() }"><i class="icon-plus"></i>&nbsp;@Resources.ButtonAdd</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: function () { showEditTrigger() }"><i class="icon-edit"></i>&nbsp;@Resources.ButtonEdit</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#modalConfirm" data-toggle="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="click: function () { deletedTrigger() }"><i class="icon-trash"></i>&nbsp;@Resources.ButtonDel</a></li>                                   
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of going around this. One question is weather you wish to pass parameters to the function that will alert the user(for example name).

```
<a class="btn btn-danger deleteBtn" 
    data-delete-arguments='{"Id":"@model.Id", "param2":"@model.param2"}' 
    data-delete-action="/YourControler/YourAction" 
    data-delete-message="Are you sure you wish to delete..." 
    href="#" 
    rel="tooltip" 
    title="Delete">
    <i class="icon-trash icon-white icon-remove"></i>
    Delete
</a>
```

This way you have all you need in data tags and can then parse out with a js function. Simply add it somewhere and you are set. In my case the function calls an action which deletes the record and then returns a partial view.

```
$('.deleteBtn').click(function (event) {
    $this = $(this);

    var modelArguments = $this.data("deleteArguments");
    var deleteMessage = $this.data("deleteMessage");
    var action = $this.data("deleteAction");

    bootbox.confirm(deleteMessage, function (result) {
        if (result) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: action,
                data: modelArguments,
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#gridcontainer').html(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Note that if the delete button is part of the partial view when it is replaced with ajax the event event will not be attached. It will only work the first time so you might need to rebind it.

In that case simply put the above js code in a function

```
function rebindDeleteButton() {
    ...
}
```

And call that function in your partial view.

This is an example if you are doing this in c#

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(int Id, string param2)
{
    //your delete code
    return PartialView("YourPartialView");
}
```

Comment: I will post a more detailed description when i come home.